# Preincrement in java

Tags: java

I have the following code fragment. No problem with it:

```
while (++left < to && less(a[left], a[from]));
```

where left is some array index, less(a, b) is helper function that returns true iff a <= b; a - array[from <= array index < to]

I particularly don't understand difference of the upper code from this:

```
 while (left < to && less(a[++left], a[from]));
```

As I have read, the preincreement evaluetes before the whole expression, but that is not the case (when i first used it I got the out of bound exception).
Can someone, please, clarify this issue?

APPEND:
Code for less:

```
private boolean less(T a, T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b) <= 0;
}
```

Comment: Part of the issue may be that && short-circuits. I can't give a full explanation, but I'd rather rewrite it to be unambiguous and not have to worry about details like that. (It may help to show code for `less`)

Comment: The "preincrement evaluates before whole expression" you have either taken out of context or your source is explaining it ambigous or you misunderstood it. "Expression" in this case can only mean the expression ++ is applied to, not the entire expression in which it occurs. Evaluation order is strictly ruled by operator precedence and then left to right.

Comment: @ Durandal Thanks, that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference between the placement comes from *not* executing `++` when `left` equal to `to-1`: this means that `++left` is equal to `to`, making `<` evaluate to `false`. This, in turn, leads to omitting the call to `less(...)` altogether due to short-circuiting of `&&`, thus preventing the exception.

When you move `++` into `a[++left]`, you end up with one more iteration, which throws the out-of-bounds exception when `left` reaches `to-1`. After pre-incrementing, `left` becomes equal to `to`, which is out of bound for the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet, first condition will evaluate to true upto max value of `to - 1`; which will cause second condition to evaluate with `left` value equal to `to` due to pre-increment. This is what may cause the index-out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: Hi, my bad if my answer missed the point  in someway; it would be really good to know exactly what was not right or unclear though.  Thanks.

Comment: that's clear, that it causes an exception-I was able to figure it out. My problem was that I misunderstood the phrase "evaluates before expression" applies only to expression for preincrement and preincrement is treated like an ordinary operator in expression as Durandal specified in his comment. Thanks for your answer.